# @Autowired returns null in Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot in my project and registering a `Bean` as follows:

```
@Bean
public Config registerBean() {
    Config config = new Config();
    config.setTest(test);

    return config;
}
```

When I try to acquire the bean, I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

```
public class PdiClient {
    @Autowired
    private Config appConfig;

}
```

Any idea on what causing the null pointer?

Comment: Not nearly enough code to tell, but this is the most likely scenario. We can reopen if you provide details that point to a different problem.

Comment: Looks like `PdiClient` is not a spring managed bean. Do you have an Annotation on class Level of this class? How you create/autowire the class?

Comment: PidClient has no annotation, it's a POJO, Do I need to add a annotation for the using class too?..

Comment: put `@Component` annotation on `PdiClient` class

Comment: Got it working, I was doing a new in a calling object. Stupid me.